# Why does Spring AOP intercept protected methods under certain circumstances?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I read that Spring AOP cannot intercept private and protected methods but it is intercepting them in a weird way why is that?

I have these functions i want to intercept:

```
public String getName(String string) {
   System.out.println("Name : " + name + string);
   return name;
}

protected String getNamesprotected(String string) {
  System.out.println("Name : " + name + string);
  return name;
}
```

This is my `@Aspect` code:

```
@Aspect
public class Logging {

    @Before("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.Student.*Name*(..))")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){
       System.out.println("Going to setup student profile."+joinPoint.getSignature().toString());
    }
}
```

When this code is executed both getName and getNamesprotected are intercepted but when I execute this code :

```
@Aspect
public class Logging {

    @Before("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.Student.getNamesprotected(..))")
    public void beforeAdvice1(JoinPoint joinPoint){
       System.out.println("Going to setup student profile."+joinPoint.getSignature().toString());
    }
}
```

Then nothing is intercepted. I also tried replacing `getNamesprotected` with `*getNamesprotected*` but still it does not intercept. It only intercepts when `*Name*` is there.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: What you describe is hard to believe unless you use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. I just think you made a mistake. Spring AOP will never intercept protected methods. If you still think it does, please prove it with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on GitHub. Then I would be willing to take a look.

Comment: Can you give an example SSCCE. I am new here so don't exactly know how to create one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the OP (Prateek Gupta) seemed to be unable (rather unwilling) to create a little [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing the problem and I was just bored during a tea break, I quickly created one by myself with Spring Boot and was very surprised that indeed Spring AOP, in contradiction to the documentation, at least under certain circumstance matches against protected methods when CGLIB proxies are involved.

Thus, I registered myself an account for Spring's Jira issue tracker and reported this regression as [SPR-15354](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15354). You might want to subscribe for updates on that ticket if interested in answers by the Spring development team.

---

**Update:** The person answering to my ticket told me that this is a documentation issue. As [SPR-1611](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1611) from 2006 tells us, this was already changed on purpose for Spring 1.2.7 but has never found its way into the documentation. Bottom line: Protected methods can be captured via Spring AOP, it is not an accident but has been undocumented for 12 years.

---

**Update 2:** The updated documentation text will be in the next Spring release. If you want to read the fixed text today, it is quoted in [SPR-1611](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1611).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And to clarify I'm not lazy it's just that I'm new to the industry not even graduate right now. I haven't used GitHub before and neither did i use StackOverflow very much. It's my first time working in an industry(1 month into the internship) in my life. I did read the manual on SSCCE and understood what it is but since i don't know about GitHub i was not able to create one that is why i asked for a sample so that i can at least understand how it is done.

Comment: Dear Prateek, how is being new to the industry or to StackOverflow an impediment concerning the creation of a little, reduced-to-minimum, stand-alone example which reproduces your problem? I cannot see that. Sorry, but if you have a reproduceable problem in your code you should also be able to extract a minimal version of it from your big project into a smaller one. You do not need to graduate in order to be able to do that. And being able to check your code into a Git repo is such a basic development skill, how can any dev survive without it? You can learn it in a day.

Comment: I have just updated my answer with the new ticket status and an explanation.

Comment: if protected can be captured by Spring AOP then why is it that when i am giving the full method name then it is not getting captured?

Comment: I have insufficient information to answer because you only provide snippets, not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So I can only speculate that probably you have a typo in your pointcut. Maybe the package name is wrong, maybe `getNamesprotected` is in reality `getNamesProtected` with capital "P". For me it works no matter which variation I try, full method name or with `*`. This time it is up to you to fix your own program. Good luck, this is the end of our discussion.

Answer (score 6):

> Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, protected methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies (where this isn’t applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes).

As a consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods only!

If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework.

> When this code is executed both getName and getNamesprotected are
>   intercepted

```
 @Before("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.Student.*Name*(..))")
```

Here the preceding wildcard matches methods with any modifier (public, protected, and private) and any return type. The two dots in the argument list match any number of arguments.

Try this it should execute your protected method

```
@Pointcut("execution(protected * *.*(..))")
```

Also you can try this if it works for you (I am not 100% sure)

```
 @Before("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.Student+.getNamesprotected(..))")
```

Comment: While what you say is all correct, it does not answer the OP's original question.

Comment: Neither `@Pointcut("execution(protected * *.*(..))")` nor `@Before("execution(* com.tutorialspoint.Student+.getNamesprotected(..))")` is working to intercept the protected method only the `*Name*` in my question is intercepting the protected which ideally should not happen since i'm using Spring AOP.