# Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed Error?

Tags: java, spring, aop, pointcut

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyDemoLogginAspect {

    @Before("execution(* * add*())")
    public void beforeAddAccountAdvice(){

        System.out.println("Executing before");

    }
}
```

I am getting an exception of Caused by:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 14
execution(* * add*())
```

I need to know why the above pointcut expression is wrong?

Note: This error is coming after execution of the main class but there is nothing wrong with the main class and the error is instead within the pointcut expression

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect pointcut expression.

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) .

The format of an execution expression is:

```
execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern 
declaring-type-pattern?name-pattern(param-pattern)throws-pattern?)
```

The correct format for your example to work is

```
@Before("execution(* add*())")
```

The modifiers-pattern is optional and cannot be a wildcard (*) and should be one of public or protected . Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42855681/4214241)

So the pointcut expression may also be

```
@Before("execution(public * add*())")
```

Also note that your pointcut expression is too global and can result in undesired result as kriegaex points out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59605704/4214241) to another SO question